# Python: Recursive Function. How to return all subsets of targetsum

Tags: python, recursion

My code is not showing  the shortest subset eg [7] or it is not reading all the subsets, [7], [3,4] to return the shortest subset. Can explain why only 1 set of result is return and how should I modify it to show all subset? Thanks

Image of Code that i wanted to follow as below

[image]

```
def howsum(targetsum,numbers,combo=None):
    
    if combo == None:
        combo = list()
    if targetsum == 0: return [ ]
    if targetsum < 0: return None
    shortcombo = None
    
    for number in numbers:
        remainder = targetsum - number      
        
        combo = howsum(remainder,numbers,combo)
        if combo != None:
            combo.append(number)
            if shortcombo == None or len(shortcombo) > len(combo):
                shortcombo = combo
                return shortcombo
                                    
    return shortcombo
     
print(howsum(7,[4,3,7]))
```

Comment: Have you tried [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)? Try manually walking through the code, and see if you arrive at the result you want, and how you get there. It should be pretty evident where something's going on.

Comment: [link] https://youtu.be/oBt53YbR9Kk i tried duplicating the logic from this youtube link. But i failed. Will try read up on the debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrote code that closely matches the original JavaScript.

Although JavaScript names will work, I refactored function and variable names to agree with [Python style](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names), namely:

- Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.
- Variable names follow the same convention as function names.

**Code**

```
def best_sum(target_sum, numbers):
    if target_sum == 0: return []
    if target_sum < 0: return None
    
    shortest_combination = None

    for num in numbers:
        remainder = target_sum - num
        remainder_combination = best_sum(remainder, numbers)
        if remainder_combination != None:
            combination = [*remainder_combination, num] # Python * equivalent to JavaSscript ...
            if shortest_combination == None or len(combination) < len(shortest_combination):
                shortest_combination = combination
    
    return shortest_combination
```

**Test**

```
print(bestSum(7, [3, 4, 7])) # Output: [7]
```

**Using Memoization (i.e. caching)**

```
def best_sum(target_sum, numbers, memo = None):
    if memo is None:
        memo = {0:[]}
    if target_sum < 0:
        return None
    if target_sum in memo:
        return memo[target_sum]

    shortest_combination = None

    for num in numbers:
        remainder = target_sum - num

        remainder_combination = best_sum(remainder, numbers, memo)
        if remainder_combination != None:
            combination = [*remainder_combination, num] # Python * equivalent to JavaSscript ...
            if shortest_combination == None or len(combination) < len(shortest_combination):
                shortest_combination = combination

    memo[target_sum] = shortest_combination

    return memo[target_sum]

print(best_sum(7, [3, 4, 7]))  # Output: 7
# Following very slow on non-memoized version
print(best_sum(100,[10,1,25])) # Output: [25, 25, 25, 25]
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about this but while defining a function in python and giving 2 sets of codes it is not actually performing the second set of the code when calling out the function. I got the same problem with some other project. And I got no answers but saying I did some wrong in the code!!!

Comment: [link] https://youtu.be/oBt53YbR9Kk i followed the code from this video. But i cant get the same result. Can you explain the difference?

Answer (score 1):

Added memoization, however with 1 inside sets of num. the results gone haywire.

```
def best_sum(target_sum, numbers,memo=None):
    if memo == None:
      memo = dict()
    
    if target_sum in memo:
      return memo[target_sum]
  
    if target_sum == 0: return []
    if target_sum < 0: return None
    
    shortest_combination = None

    for num in numbers:
        remainder = target_sum - num
        remainder_combination = best_sum(remainder, numbers,memo)
        if remainder_combination != None:
            remainder_combination.append(num)
            combination = remainder_combination
            if shortest_combination == None or len(combination) < len(shortest_combination):
                shortest_combination = combination
    memo[target_sum] = shortest_combination
    return shortest_combination

print(best_sum(100,[5,1,25]))
```

This code by answer posted by DarylG works. By changing the `.append` to `[*list,var]` However I dont understand why is the result different between function append and *

```
def best_sum(target_sum, numbers,memo=None):
    if memo == None:
      memo = dict()
    
    if target_sum in memo:
      return memo[target_sum]
  
    if target_sum == 0: return []
    if target_sum < 0: return None
    
    shortest_combination = None

    for num in numbers:
        remainder = target_sum - num
        remainder_combination = best_sum(remainder, numbers,memo)
        if remainder_combination != None:
            combination = [*remainder_combination,num] #this line from append to *
            if shortest_combination == None or len(combination) < len(shortest_combination):
                shortest_combination = combination
    memo[target_sum] = shortest_combination
    return shortest_combination

print(best_sum(100,[5,1,25]))
```

Comment: @josephgan--Hi Joseph--for your test case this code does not return the shortest subset for your test case.  It returns [4, 3] rather than [7].  I'll post an answer that closely matches the JavaScript code that returns the correct result.

Comment: Hi I miss wrote the < on the comparing len. it shall be len(shortcombo) > len(combo).

I will read up your solution with the * function. didnt know have this usage as well. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @josephgan--good catch.  You should update your answer with the correction.

Comment: Hi Darry, i re-tried with implementing memoization with my code. However, if num contains 1 `eg (100,[10,1,25]`. With my solution of using append, the results gone haywire.  However, with using the * function. It return the actual result. Could you explain why? However, without implementing memoization, with 1 inside the num, my solution is not mesed up.

Comment: Hi Daryl. Rechecked. The append solution does'nt work with huge number. Nothing to do with memoziation. Not sure why.

Comment: @josephgan--I upvoted your answer for all the work you're done.  A simple fix (that may tell you why the append doesn't work is to instead use: `combination = remainder_combination + [num]`, which is equivalent to: `combination = [*remainder_combination,num]`.  The problem is with append and memorization, multiple solutions in the memo cache are referencing the same array.  When you append to one, you're appending to them all.  The `combination = remainder_combination + [num]` creates distinct arrays for the solutions, so no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I checked out your code. What I felt missing was

- Incorrect placement of return and storing the values inside of combo (set
  instead of list).

  ```
   def howsum(targetsum,numbers,combo=None):
       if combo == None:
           combo = set()
       if targetsum == 0: 
           return [ ]
       if targetsum < 0: 
           return None

       for idx,number in enumerate(numbers):
           remainder = targetsum - number
           if howsum(remainder,numbers[idx:],combo) != None:
               combo.add(number)
       else:
           return combo
       return None
  ```

`print(howsum(7,[7,3,4,2,5]))`

Hope this helps. While this gives you a solution I would recommend using a different way to solve such issues (twoSum solutions) or two pointer approach with O(n).

Comment: Hi, i tried the code it return all the possible combination in a set. May i know how to separate it into eg [3,4] & [7]?. Hi also, for numbers of [2,6] it should return None.

I followed this youtube video, but i can't duplicate the logic. [link] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oBt53YbR9Kk&t=7613s. In the video, is the python-equivalent list used? or it is a set.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using memo/any variable for memoization, you can employ functools.lru_cache method. **Just remember to typecast the input while testing**.

```
import functools

@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=4)
def howsum(targetnum, num_list):
    if targetnum == 0:
        return []
    if targetnum < 0:
        return None
    for num in num_list:
        rem = targetnum - num
        rem_val = howsum(rem, num_list)
        if rem_val is not None:
            rem_val.append(num)
            return rem_val
    return None

print(howsum(7, tuple([5, 3, 4, 7])))
print(howsum(8, tuple([3, 4, 2])))
print(howsum(300, tuple([7, 14])))
```